# The named parameter 'child' isn't defined

Tags: flutter

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  child: AlertDialog( // this line error
    shape: defaultCardBorder(),
    title: Row(
      children: [
        _icon,
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        Expanded(child: Text(_title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)))
      ],
    ),
    content: Text(
      message,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
    ),
    actions: [
      /// Negative button
      negativeAction == null
          ? Container(width: 0, height: 0)
          : FlatButton(
              onPressed: negativeAction,
              child: Text(negativeText ?? "CANCEL",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.grey))),

      /// Positive button
      FlatButton(
          onPressed: positiveAction ?? () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          child: Text(positiveText ?? "OK",
              style: _textStyle)),
    ],
  ));
```

**> How To Fix this Problem In flutter**
child line error. error was The named parameter 'child' isn't defined.
The named parameter 'child' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the

Answer (score 2):

I guess you use Flutter 2.0. Since this update [AlertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) doesn't have a child property anymore. Instead you have to declare a **builder**.

```
showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('MyTitle'),
            content: Container(),
          ),
        );
```